# React Native Linking.openURL not working in Headless

Tags: linker, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-firebase

I am using **@react-native-firebase/messaging** and running a **headless** task in which I am successfully getting the Notification when console.logging, but if I use Linking.openURL('myappurl://screen') nothing is working.

Here are the code for **index.js**

```
import {AppRegistry, DeviceEventEmitter, Linking} from 'react-native';

import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

const getNofification = async (message) => {
  console.log('Console => ', message);
  Linking.openURL('whatsup://call/');
  return Promise.resolve();
};

// messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (notif) => {
//   console.log('Notification => ', notif);
//   Linking.openURL(
//     'whatsup://chat/1234/',
//   );
// });

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
  'ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask',
  () => getNofification,
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Same are working fine if i open the deeplink inside App.js.

Comment: Can you provide some code example of what you tried so far?

Comment: added, please check now